# MySQL insert multiple records and reference them in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to make this inquiry as generic as possible, I don't want to get into specifics but rather to learn a generally accepted approach to this problem.

I have some data, structured like this:

```
$data => Array
    (
     [0] => Array
           (
            [field_index] => 2
            [comment] => damage of object 1
            [image] => Array
                   (
                    [url] => /path/to/file/my_image.jpg
                    [fname] => my_image.jpg
                    [fsize] => 77005
                    )

            ),
      [1] ...
      [2] ...

     )
```

I am trying to insert this in two tables `files` and `records`, were image data is stored in the first and the record data with reference to image ID is stored in the second.

The only way I can do it is to loop through all items and run an `INSERT` queries one by one, like so:

```
foreach($data as $item){

// INSERT IMAGE TO FILES TABLE
// GET INSERT_ID
// INSERT ITEM DATA TO RECORDS (USE INSERT_ID OF IMAGE AS REFERENCE)
}
```

My question is:

a) is this OK to run insert queries one-by-one as opposed to  inserting multiple rows in a single query?
b) is there an alternative method of achieving what I am after - referencing  data in two tables.

I want to keep file data separately because:

- not all records may have image data
- `$data` may have revisions, where some records could change but not all, and I don't want redundant image records

Comment: It is OK with me. :-) You could use a single insert for the records data.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options -

1. You can insert the records individually starting with the parent and finishing with the children. You can use Last_Insert_Id to get the last id inserted into MySQL, which allows you to insert a parent, get it's primary key and then include it in any insert on the child records. I generally return the Last_Insert_Id as an output parameter in a MySQL stored proc so the calling code can manage it.

You can also insert multiple rows into the table with a single insert command - this is a much faster way of inserting lots of records.

2. Use an ORM (object-relational manager) so that you can just insert the data into objects in your code, meaning you don't have to worry about the SQL side of things as the ORM wrapper handles the communication with the database for you. This is quite a big change for an existing project, but could be worthwhile.

One note on ORMs - a lot that I have dealt with don't do bulk inserts of thousands or tens of thousands of records particularly well, so SQL may be your best bet in that instance.